# Elegant integration method I'm missing...

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Compute $r'(t)$, where
>
> $$r(t) = \left(\int_1^{t^2} s^6 e^s ds \right) \textbf i +
>  \exp\left(-\int_1^t\arctan(s) ds\right) \textbf j$$
>
> *Hint*: for the $i$ part, there is a significantly more elegant method than integration by parts

Just started a differential equations class and I haven't taken calculus in about 3 years. Trying to do some practice problems. Any idea what the more elegant method is in the hint section? Also I'm a bit confused how the i and j will affect this. This is some sort of vector correct? Like I said, it's been awhile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus: if
$$ F(x) = \int_a^x f(y) \, dy, $$
then $F'(x) = f(x)$ (with some conditions on $f$ like continuity). In this case you can't quite apply this directly, but you can do it using the chain rule: for example, the ${\bf i}$ component can be done by setting $g(t)=t^2$, then
$$ \frac{d}{dt} F(g(t)) = g'(t) F'(g(t)) = g'(t) f(g(t)), $$
in this case, $f(s) = s^6 e^s$, so the derivative of the ${\bf i}$ component is
$$ 2t \cdot (t^2)^6 e^{t^2} = 2t^{13} e^{t^2}. $$
The ${\bf j}$ component will yield to using the chain rule, but in a slightly different way; since they have not evaluated the arctangent integral, it's not clear (to me, at least) whether they want you to.

Comment: Any thoughts on the j component. I'm fairly lost. I solved the integral I believe. I got the integral of arctan(s) ds to be s*arctan(s)-(1/2)ln|$s^2$+1|, but where do I got from here.

Comment: Remember that $\frac{d}{dx} e^{F(x)} = F'(x) e^{F(x)}$, so you don't have to do the integral to get the $F'(x)$ (FToC applies again). The only place you need to evaluate the integral for is in the exponential itself.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf i$ usually means the first vector of the canonical base. It just means the first component of the vector $r(t)$

Using the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign), one finds (for $\textbf i$) that

$$\frac d{dt} \int_1^{t^2}s^6e^s ds = 2t^{13}e^{t^2}$$